# Using not equal to operator in Prolog

Tags: prolog

In Prolog my facts are as follows.

```
flows(godavari,andhra).
flows(krishna,telangana).
flows(krishna,andhra).
```

**I want to frame a query for list of rivers that flows through andhra but not in telangana.**

I tried with

```
fl(X,Y,Z):- flows(X,Y), flows(X,Z).
```

which lists all the rivers that pass through 
Y and Z.

**I want river passes through Y and not Z.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `not` operator:

```
fl(X,Y,Z) :- flows(X,Y), not(flows(X,Z)).
```

Comment: `not/1` is deprecated. `(\+)/2` is the ISO "not provable" predicate: `\+ flows(X,Z)`.

Comment: @lurker it works fine, but what is "not provable predicate"?

Comment: "not provable" is what `not/1` and `(\+)/1` really mean. See documentation for more details. Yes, `not/1` will "work" but it's not supported in all Prologs. `(\+)/1` is the ISO standard predicate.